# Could not resolve all dependencies error in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

Can any one tell me why I got the error as I was building a simple chat application in Android Studio v2.2:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.4. Required by: Simplemessaging:app:unspecified

Comment: Most likely you placed the Play Services dependency in the wrong place. Show your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Delete the .gradle folder in c->user->name->.gradle  and rebuild the project. it will take some time to build nearly 10min. wait with patience